# C++ sfinae design pattern

Tags: c++, qt, templates, sfinae

can somebody tell me how to solve this problem in c++ ?

error is

> no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'QList' and
>   'Form1*')
>            *this->list << form1;

myobj.h

```
#ifndef MYOBJ_H
#define MYOBJ_H
#include <QList>
#include "form.h"
#include "form1.h"

template <typename T>
class MyObj
{
public:
    MyObj(QList<T*>* list)
    {
        this->list = list;

        if (std::is_same<T,Form>::value) {
            form = new Form;
            *this->list << form;
        }
        if (std::is_same<T,Form1>::value) {
            form1 = new Form1;
            *this->list << form1;
        }
    }

    QList<T*>* list = NULL;
    Form* form = NULL;
    Form1* form1 = NULL;
};

#endif // MYOBJ_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
myObj = new MyObj<Form>(new QList<Form*>);
```

thank you for helping me

**I edited**

Comment: This looks like you come from a Java or C# background. You don't need to use new everywhere in C++. What do you want to do with the `<<` operator?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve with `*this->list << form;`?

Comment: sry as posted 1 min after submitting the question, I did an edit to the code

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Apparently `QList` overloads `<<` to do the equivalent of `push_back`.

Comment: @T.C. Should the question be tagged [tag:qt] then?

Comment: I added the tag Qt

Comment: Not sure what this question has to do with SFINAE.   Nothing in the code you posted seems relevant to your title.

Comment: sure it has to do with sfinae or you know an other soluition for this. I think enable_if is the way to go am I right?

Comment: For something like this, just throw in a couple `reinterpret_cast<T*>`'s. The only reachable code paths are the safe ones anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I post an answer myself, cause I found one. Is this the right approach to solve the problem? I'm very interested in design-patterns.

```
#ifndef MYOBJ_H
#define MYOBJ_H
#include <QList>
#include "form.h"
#include "form1.h"
#include <QDebug>

template <typename T>
class MyObj
{
public:
    MyObj(QList<T*>* list)
    {
        this->list = list;

        if (std::is_same<T,Form>::value) {
            form = new Form;
            appendFunc(form);
        }
        else if (std::is_same<T,Form1>::value) {
            form1 = new Form1;
            appendFunc(form1);
        }
    }

    QList<T*>* list = NULL;
    Form* form = NULL;
    Form1* form1 = NULL;

    template <typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,U>::value,void>
    appendFunc(U* a) {
        qDebug() << "test100";
        *this->list << a;
    }

    void appendFunc(...) { }
};

#endif // MYOBJ_H
```

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the template parameter?

```
template <typename T>
class MyObj
{
public:
    MyObj()
    {
        list.push_back( new T );
    }

private:
    QList<T*> list;
};
```